# Build multiple application versions with angular

Tags: angular

I want to create an Angular application that supports multiple versions: A 'free-version' and a 'pro-version'. Assuming the following code structure

```
app
├───app.module.ts
├───app.component.ts|html|css
├───free-version
│   ├───feature-1
│   └───feature-2
└───pro-version
    ├───feature-3
    └───feature-4
```

How can I get my Angular project to support:

- a build for the free-version to contain only feature-1 and feature-2
- an additional build for the pro-version that contains all features from the free-version plus feature-3 and feature-4

Comment: Why have separate builds? Seems more logical to me to just use different paths with guards and maybe lazy loading

Comment: The application will be an offline application. The downloaded free-version should not contain features of the pro-version.

Comment: Sounds like you’re really implementing security very poorly if your restrictions require users to not have an app downloaded. No app I’ve worked on in the real world with free and premium features works this way. The restrictions to premium content or features happens at the server. This offline app of yours could just be downloaded and purchased by one person and shared to others trivially.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with security. I just want to know how I can structure my app to support different builds. Paid/free version should just give an simple example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Part of being on this board and participating is evaluating the problem the question is attempting to solve. The problem in your question appears to be, on a deeper level, how to keep premium and free content separate, and the solution you’ve chosen is creating different builds, and you’re asking now how to implement this solution. Based on my experience and knowledge, your solution is the wrong approach, and you should reevaluate your options. This is an attempt to help you and not an attack in anyway. Posing a question on this board will attract all sorts of responses. Be open to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for you is to create 2 folders: `freemium`, `premium`

Later edit [angular.json](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config) and set 2 projects, make sure to define the correct path to the relevant `index.html` and `main.ts` per project.

```
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"projects": {
    "freemium": {
        "root": "src",
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "projectType": "application",
        "architect": {
            "build": {
                "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                "options": {
                    "outputPath": "dist",
                    "index": "src/freemium/index.html",
                    "main": "src/freemium/main.ts",
                    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                    "assets": [
                        "src/assets",
                        "src/favicon.ico",
                        "src/manifest.json"
                    ],
                    "styles": [
                        "src/styles.scss"
                    ],
                    "scripts": []
                },
                "configurations": {
                    "production": { ... },
                    "staging": { ... }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "premium": { ... }
    }
},
```

Additional solution will be to use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) with different `webpack.config.js` for each project.

Please note that you must handle the authorization layer on server side, and not assuming that client side protection is good enough.

The best solution for you is to combine between angular [route-guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) and a server side authorization.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for [angular workspaces](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config).